# Why is there a glitch in JRadioButtons after resizing the Frame vertically in runtime?

Tags: java, swing

when I click the different radio buttons multiple times, some radio buttons will be selected automatically creating two radio buttons that are selected even though I added them on the ButtonGroup. The radio buttons work fine even after resizing the Frame horizontally.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class B extends JFrame {

        private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
        private JPanel buttonPanel;
        private JLabel label;
        private final int FONT_SIZE = 40;

        public B() {

            setSize(500, 500);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            label = new JLabel("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
            label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

            addRadioButton("small", 8);     
            addRadioButton("medium", 15);
            addRadioButton("large", 25);
            addRadioButton("extra-large", 40);

            add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            pack();

        }
        public void addRadioButton(String buttonLabel, int size) {

            boolean selected = size == FONT_SIZE;
            JRadioButton rButton = new JRadioButton(buttonLabel, selected);
            rButton.setFocusable(false);
            buttonGroup.add(rButton);
            buttonPanel.add(rButton);

            ActionListener listener = event -> label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, size));
            rButton.addActionListener(listener);
        }   

        public static void main(String...args) {
            B b = new B();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move this line of your code: `setVisible(true)` to after this line: `pack();` Both those lines appear in the constructor of class `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code (see below).

When I ran your original code, I noticed two things.

- When I clicked on a radio button, the black dot indicating that the button is selected, did not appear until I moved the mouse pointer off the button.
- When it appeared that two radio buttons are selected, when I moved the mouse pointer over the button that shouldn't be selected, the black dot disappeared.

This made me think that it has to do with the paint mechanism in *Swing*. When you change the font of the `JLabel` your GUI needs to be repainted. Also when you select a `JRadioButton` your GUI needs to be repainted. So your `ActionListener` was probably creating a situation that the *Swing* paint mechanism was not handling correctly.

For this reason there exists methods `revalidate()` and `repaint()` in class `java.awt.Component`. Hence in the below code, I added calls to those two methods inside the `ActionListener` lambda expression.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class B extends JFrame {
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JLabel label;
    private final int FONT_SIZE = 40;

    public B() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        label = new JLabel("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        addRadioButton("small", 8);     
        addRadioButton("medium", 15);
        addRadioButton("large", 25);
        addRadioButton("extra-large", 40);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addRadioButton(String buttonLabel, int size) {
        boolean selected = size == FONT_SIZE;
        JRadioButton rButton = new JRadioButton(buttonLabel, selected);
        rButton.setFocusable(false);
        buttonGroup.add(rButton);
        buttonPanel.add(rButton);

        ActionListener listener = event -> {
            label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, size));

            // Added these lines which fixes the problem.
            Container contentPane = getContentPane();
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
        };
        rButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }   

    public static void main(String...args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm true about this, I think you need get into Swing stuffs using event-dispatched.

In main, go like this

```java
public static void main(String...args) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     new B();
   }
});

}
```

Comment: @user13721084 this didn't work, sir. but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @JoseBhraynColina, yes this is good advice that should ALWAYS be followed. Swing components should be created and updated on the EDT.

Comment: @JoseBhraynColina using a Lamda is fine. Some people like lamdas and some people don't.

Comment: @camickr Thanks, such a helpful answer! :)